# Javascript Countdown doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Everytime I reload this page http://prince27.bplaced.net/Prince27-Website/html/slider_true.html, the countdown starts all over again. What did I do wrong?

I've set the endDate to 20 september 2012 and calculated the milliseconds between now & endDate.

```
var today = new Date();

var endDate = new Date("20/09/2012"); //set the date you want timer to end
var diffMs = (280800000); // milliseconds between now & endDate
var diffDays = Math.round(diffMs / 86400000); // days
var diffHrs = Math.round((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
var diffSecs = Math.floor((((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) % 60000) / 1000);
```

Full script [file](http://prince27.bplaced.net/Prince27-Website/html/js/countdown.engine.js)

Answer (score 5):

You've hardcoded the difference:

```
var diffMs = (280800000); // milliseconds between now & endDate
```

Answer (score 3):

Review your code, you have hardcoded value for `diffMs` and you never use `today`

```
var today = new Date();

var endDate = new Date("20/09/2012"); //set the date you want timer to end
var diffMs = (280800000); // milliseconds between now & endDate
```

Comment: Thank you. Please tell me what I should code instead. I'm a beginner, sorry.

Comment: @MarkusOkur calculate difference in milliseconds between `endDate` and `today` and put it in `diffMs` variable.

Comment: But I've done this in the code above! '280800000' are the milliseconds between now and Thursday 10PM...

Comment: @MarkusOkur: the amount of milliseconds to a given date will change every millisecond. It cannot be a hard coded value. It *was* `280800000` when you performed the calculation.